# The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

We have an ASP.NET v4.0 IIS Webapp and we are getting this error a few times a day and it requires a reboot of the domain controllers to fix.  There are no real issues with the trust that I can see.  With two servers running the web app one can work while another shows this error. The issue happens when we contact Active Directory to get a users roles so that we can build a menu. When the issue comes up, I cannot remote debug the app.

This is the line that starts off the error:

> System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection
>   sourceAccounts, Boolean& someFailed) +1085

I have tried unjoining and rejoining the web server to the domain.  And have followed this kb article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324383/troubleshooting-scecli-1202-events that talks about users with spaces in their name.  So far no luck.

Is there anything else I can check?  Are there some safeguards I can put into the app to help mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that we had was caused by our application checking to see if a user was in a security group that did not exist.  Once we updated it so that it only validated against existing security groups, the problem went away.

Comment: Yea, it looks like the security group must exist even if the user is not a member of it. Kinda sucks but I suppose I can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you are not connected to domain also cause this issue, I solved.